# How to start Java main thread like a daemon thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

I need to start my java class like a background process without using jsvc. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linux you can easily do it with :

```
java -jar myjar.jar &
```

Under windows you can try using the `javaw` instead of `java` :

```
javaw -jar myjar.jar
```

Otherwise you will need [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html) service or daemon wrapper.

Comment: Thank you very much. I needed command for Windows. It works ^_^

Comment: @EJP Yep. I don't need daemon thread exactly. Just wanna start app in background.